# 64 Bit Windows drivers for Inspiron 1720

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit

Dell doesn't seem to offer 64 bit drivers specifically for the Inspiron 1720 (laptop). I'm going to be upgrading from Vista 32-bit to Windows 7 64bit and I want to pull down the necessary stuff before hand.

Are there any Dell systems that are similar enough to the Inspiron 1720 that I can use for a baseline to make sure I still have Ethernet and WiFi after the reinstall? It doesn't matter if they are for Vista 64 or Windows 7.

Identified hardware:

- Processor: Intel mobile Core 2 Duo T7500
- Chipset: Intel Mobile 965 Express
- Wifi: Intel Pro Wireless
- Drive Controller: Intel Matrix
- Graphics: nVidia GeForce 8600M GT
- Bluetooth: Dell TrueMobile 355 + EDR
- Ricoh card reader
- I think anything else, the default Windows drivers will be sufficient. Let me know if you think I missed something thing please.

Comment: Have you tried the Win7 upgrade advisor?

Comment: @Andrew, the upgrade advisor only gives you a rudimentary pass/fail on whether or not you meet the minimum system requirements. What I am looking for are the more obscure drivers I may need. I did run it, just in case and passed on all measures.

Comment: I went x64 for the first time when I installed Win7 x64 on my Inspiron 1501. I had *no* problems with drivers on my laptop - Windows 7 had all the drivers I needed. My only problem was with my networked Dell Laser 1700 - it took a bit of work to get my server to offer up a 64-bit driver, since Dell doesn't provide one (the server now thinks it's a Lexmark printer, as Dell printers are just rebranded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Dell does not offer 64-bit drivers for the laptop specifically, the best thing to do is to go into device manager and find out exactly what hardware you have, then search the vendor's website.

I've found some for you already:

- [Chipset](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx?ProductID=2800)
- [Wireless](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx?ProductID=2753)
- [Audio](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/RedirectFTPSite.aspx?SiteID=1&DownTypeID=3&DownID=558&PFid=23&Conn=3)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your help. I'm up and running on Win7 64bit now. In addition to what [@John T linked](https://superuser.com/questions/36312/64-bit-windows-drivers-for-inspiron-1720/36321#36321), I also required and located the following:

- Wifi: Dell Wireless 1505 Draft 802.11N (Provided by Windows Update)
- Drive Controller: [Intel Matrix Storage Driver](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx?ProductID=2101)
- Graphics: [nVidia GeForce 8600M GT](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)
- Bluetooth: [Dell TrueMobile 355 + EDR](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=my&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R140135&formatcnt=1&libid=0&fileid=188664)
- Ricoh card reader (Provided by Windows Update)
- [Dell QuickSet 64 Bit](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=my&l=en&s=gen&SystemID=INSPIRON1750&servicetag=&os=WV64&osl=en&catid=-1&impid=-1&fileid=312073)
- [Alps Touchpad mouse driver](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=ap&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R213504&SystemID=INSPIRON1545&servicetag=&os=WV64&osl=en&deviceid=16519&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=17&fileid=301884)

Answer (score 1):

Stupid required first question - Does the laptop have a 64bit cpu?

If yes, read on! (sorry, but had to ask!)

If it is not officially supported, you may lose functions unique to your laptop such as quick launch or function keys.

You can go to websites such as [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com), [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/) and [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) among many others and download the drivers directly for all the hardware in your laptop.

Comment: Yeah I'm running a Core 2 Duo on the Intel 965 Express chipset. It's 64 bit capable. The drivers I am worried about are the black-box stuff like the Ethernet, Dell Wifi and DEll Bluetooth (322 I think).

Comment: yes it does have a 64bit CPU, the Pentium Dual Core T2390 is based on the 64-bit Intel Core architecture, using Merom-2M core. DELL does not yet offer any Windows 7 drivers in general and no 64bit drivers for that particular model at all. so, this is going to be trial and error :)

Comment: DELL don't make their own devices, if you run SIW on your system, you'll be able to identify the device manufacturers, (e.g. Broadcom Ethernet)

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has 64 bit CPU, then you can try out Windows 7 x64. However, you may need to use Vista x64 drivers for few devices. You can get Vista x64 drivers from Dell driver download page itself, and for Windows 7 x64 drivers you can check out these pages:
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx 
http://laptopvideo2go.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that x86 only shows 3.5 GB of RAM.

Anyway, I've switched to 64 bit Win 7 as well. Everything seems to be working but the built-in webcam. Does anyone have a driver for this stuff?
Dell on its website only offers drivers for 32 bit Vista, so I can't find any help there.

Comment: Matyy, the web cam for mine is from Creative Labs (think soundblaster). Windows update got the proper driver for me automatically. If it isn't pulling that down for you, check your Dell packing list (available online if you use your service code) you can see who made it and try their site.

Comment: Seems like I've got the same one, but somehow the windows update doesn't want to provide me with this driver. On the other hand, I can't find any exact model on dell website either. Could you give me a hand? Thanks ^^

Comment: @Matyy - got into http://support.dell.com, click the drivers and downloads button and put in your service tag form the laptop. On the left side of the screen you should be able to find a link that under Product Support that says "system configuration." That link brings you to the original packing list for your laptop. You should be able to find your camera's make and model there. If not, post the packing list as a question on SuperUser and someone can help decipher it.